# How can I get Black background in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, background-color

I was going through a page and it strikes me that I want to have same color effect. I am talking about [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017152158/http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/an-introduction-to-observablecollection-in-wpf/)

As you can see: The guy is having black codebehind color. Which tool should I use from Visual Studio Gallery?

Comment: Link is now dead and unfortunately the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627060115/http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/an-introduction-to-observablecollection-in-wpf) version appears to have lost the colours.

Comment: The [archived link from January 2011](https://web.archive.org/web/20110108115300/http://www.e-pedro.com/2009/04/an-introduction-to-observablecollection-in-wpf/) seems to have some colors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors**

Doing it manually is a repetitive annoying job, but after you finish you can save it (with all your other settings) in Environment -> Import and Export Settings. You can find **foreground recommendation** over the web (e.g. from [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingYourColorsInVisualStudioNETBlackVersusWhite.aspx)), and even **ready-to-import setting files** [like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2010/04/20/join-the-dark-side-of-visual-studio-2010.aspx) (note that it will probably write over other settings).

*In my opinion*, black background was pleasant to the eye in the old CRT screens, but a bit too bright with LEDs & LCDs.

Answer (score 8):

http://studiostyl.es/schemes

see this coders....

Answer (score 3):

Rather than setting up your own colour scheme I'd suggest using a vssettings file that someone has already made and shared on the web.

I use metroline.

http://winterdom.com/2010/04/metroline-a-vs2010-color-scheme

Try this and see what you think.

I love it for C# and css/html but find it a bit ugly for xslt.

Comment: +1 for preceding my update in 3 min. Welcome to StackOverfllow :)

Comment: Link has changed: http://www.winterdom.com/vs%20color%20scheme/2010/04/14/metroline-a-vs2010-color-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in the dark (less distraction) and white backgrounds are stressing your eyes, I suggest to make *everything* black. Thats at least possible with the Windows 8 Magnifier Tool. Click on "Options" and check "Invert Colors".